# Не освобождается память в Си

Tags: c

Есть следующая структура:

```
typedef struct _line_t {
    char *data;
    size_t length;
    size_t lineno;

    struct _line_t *next;
    struct _line_t *prev;
} line_t;
```

Как можно догадаться она предназначенна для организации связного списка строк (не спрашивайте зачем мне такой костыль и почему я не могу использовать С++).

Есть функция создания такой строки (она выделяет память под структуру и устанавливает поля. Не буду её тут приводить), а также функция удаления (освобождения памяти).

Последняя выглядит вот так:

```
void lines_delete(line_t *begin)
{
    if(!begin)
        return;

    line_t *cur = begin, *prev;

    while(cur) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;

        if(prev->data)
            free(prev->data);

        free(prev);
        prev->lineno += 1; //Для теста
    }
}
```

Вышепреведенный код не падает, но я не так давно знаком с Си и решил проверить отладчиком:

```
Breakpoint 1, lines_delete (begin=0x6032a0) at line.c:21
21      if(!begin)
(gdb) n
24      line_t *cur = begin, *prev;
(gdb) n
26      while(cur) {
(gdb) n
27          prev = cur;
(gdb) n
28          cur = cur->next;
(gdb) n
30          if(prev->data)
(gdb) n
31              free(prev->data);
(gdb) n
33          free(prev);
(gdb) n
34          prev->lineno += 1;
(gdb) n
26      while(cur) {
(gdb)
```

Т.е. вы поняли, да? Я освобождаю *prev*, а потом спокойно обращаюсь к уже освобожденной памяти. После строки 33 отладчик "говорит" что память не освобождена. Примечательно, что prev->data = 0x0, т.е. данные (массив char) получилось освободить, а саму строку (структуру) -- нет. Я в замешательстве.

**UPD**: В функцию lines_data передавал такой связной список из трех узлов (т.е. три структуры) и случайно заметил что не все prev->data освобождаются. Смотрите (продолжение вывода от gdb):

```
26      while(cur) {
(gdb) print prev->data 
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) n
27          prev = cur;
(gdb) n
28          cur = cur->next;
(gdb) n
30          if(prev->data)
(gdb) n
31              free(prev->data);
(gdb) n
33          free(prev);
(gdb) n
34          prev->lineno += 1;
(gdb) print prev->data 
$2 = 0x603290 ""
(gdb)
```

То есть data первой строки освобождается (становится 0x0), а data второй строки не освобождается, но становится пустой (как говорит отладчик).

Также gdb позволяет сделать вот так (см. ниже), а это значит что память на все 100% не освобождена. Продолжение вывода:

```
(gdb) print prev->data 
$2 = 0x603290 ""
(gdb) set prev->data = "Hello"
(gdb)
```

Теперь я уже в полном замешательстве, мой код живёт как хочет и делает что хочет?

Comment: Начнем с того, что вот такое: `free(prev); prev->lineno += 1;` - сначала освободить память, а потом к ней обращаться - категорически запрещается... И еще - освобождение памяти `free(prev)` **не** делает `prev` нулевым указателем.

Comment: И ещё, `free` совершенно адекватно реагирует на нулевой указатель. Дополнительная проверка не требуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле обращаться после освобождения памяти - UB - можно получить что угодно. *Обычно* происходит следующее: в начале блока памяти выставляется некий флаг что память свободна, после чего её можно использовать повторно. Обнуление памяти не производится в связи с большими накладными расходами (в С принято что память чистит тот, кто её попросил выделить). Поэтому при определённом везении (а скорее невезении) вы можете даже прочитать исходное значение памяти до удаления.

Что произошло у вас - prev - указатель, его значение *не изменяется* после вызова free(). (сигнатура `free(void *)` но не `free(void**)`). Следовательно вы должны *сами* написать `prev = NULL` если вам важно значение этого указателя.

> память не освобождена

Значения указателя к освобождению памяти не имеют отношения.

Comment: Я не знал, теперь буду знать. Как насчёт правильности такой функции освобождения? А то я не уверен.

Comment: после вызова `free` будет логично сделать `NULL` все указатели которые ссылались на неё или её часть. Так функция выглядит вполне правильно.

Comment: А, и ещё: Почему тогда некоторые prev->data =0x0, а некоторые нет? free же не изменяет значение указателя.

Comment: указателя нет, но вы же и сам prev удаляете, для prev - это его поле, может удалиться, может нет.

Comment: и ещё `if(prev->data)` можете не проверять, внутри free стоит эта проверка.

Comment: понял. Спасибо за ответ.